# queue implementation in C compilation error

Tags: c, struct, queue, compilation

i have a program with queues using linked lists.when i compile it, it has the following error:

> expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token >>in error_line

```
///USEFUL PART OF THE PROGRAM
//queue struct
typedef struct{
    int embros,piso,adeia;
    int pinakas[PLITHOS];
}Q;

int main(){
    Q oura_apo; //define a new queue

    dimiourgia(&oura_apo);//create the new queue

return 0;
}

//this function creates a new empty list

void dimiourgia(Q *oura){  //this is error_line
    oura->embros=0;
    oura->piso=0;
}
```

Comment: Where is main? Are you calling `dimiourgia()` from within a function? It looks like you forgot a `;` or `)` somewhere in code that's not here.

Comment: or if you could just tell me what the error means.is it "forgot a ;" for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the definition of the *dimiougia* function in between the struct declaration and main. Otherwise, you need a preceding declaration:

```
void dimiourgia(Q *oura);
```

It is not very clear where the error can happen in your program, however, that error message is typically obtained when the structure Q is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles correctly for me!

```
#define PLITHOS 10
typedef struct{    
int embros,piso,adeia;
int pinakas[PLITHOS];
}Q;
Q oura_apo; 

void dimiourgia(Q *oura){   
oura->embros=0;   
oura->piso=0;
}

int main() {
}
```

Comment: the correct answer is the one written by Baltasarq. In c/c++ you have to declare you function before you can call it.